# Check powers of 2 in one line using left shift

Tags: algorithm, bit

Can anyone suggest a way to check whether a number is power of 2 , by just using << operator  , I mean no + , - * , / ,loops. 
Something one -line sort of.
If not can u give me the smallest algo using << that comes in ur mind

Comment: What have **you** tried so far? Share **your** findings. If possible also post your code.

Answer (score 2):

If a number is the power of `2` is has only one `1` digit in the binary representation. 
I.e. `10`, `100`, `100000` etc. If you subtract one, you will get the whole `1`.
like `10-1=1`, `100-1=11` etc. That's why if you do `x&(x-1)` you will get all zeros. 
So you can use the formula below

`x && (!(x&(x-1)))`

First x in the below expression is for the case when `x` is `0`.

Comment: Um ,thanks for replying , but I kinda wanted it using <<

Comment: **I like it!** Nice and short solution and a simple to understand explanation too.

Comment: @Ayush Mangal: Why insisting of using << ? Is this some kind of homework you try to get the answer form the forum?

Comment: More or less , our teacher gave this and I am stuck , its a thing from abt 3 months back so it exactly isn't an homework

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPowerOf2(1));
        System.out.println(isPowerOf2(2));
        System.out.println(isPowerOf2(4));
        System.out.println(isPowerOf2(128));
        System.out.println(isPowerOf2(62));
    }

    private static boolean isPowerOf2(int num){
        int temp = 1;
        while(temp < num){
            temp <<= 1;
        }
        return temp == num;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
true
true
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Left shift actually multiplies the numbere by two while right shift divides it.
So if you want to check a number `num` is power of two you have to take `temp=1`and do `temp>>1` till `temp<=num`  If `temp==num` in this loop then `num` is power of two else it is not.